# What can I do to prevent injuries from the corners of a wooden deck?

Tags: deck, safety, child-safety

We recently had the floor of our wooden deck replaced and in the process, the contractor changed it from having cut-off corners to having real corners.

I am concerned with how the new corner sticks into the backyard so kids playing there might run into it.  This was previously not a problem because the deck did not have sharp corners.

What can I put on the corner to protect people in the yard that will be durable and easy to install and maintain (looking good is ideal too)?

---

**Update**

Here is a picture of the issue:

[image: Outline of Deck]

The old deck is the black outline and the new deck adds to it the red areas as well.

I currently do not have exact measurements but here is an approximation:

- The deck is approx. 20' x 10'.  There are 4 steps down to the yard on the right-hand side (not shown).
- The yard's total size is around 60' x 30' in the same orientation as the deck.  There is a swing set and a 12' octagonal trampoline as well as several trees.

Comment: Is it feasible to round or cut off the corners again? A picture (preferably with measurements as well) will help someone answer, as it's not clear how much room you have to work with.

Comment: How about a bush or other landscaping to keep people away from the corners?

Comment: Put padding on the kids instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to a Marina and get some dock corner bumpers.    It's probably the least ugly solution.

[image]

Comment: that's a really good idea! Looks nice, too.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Plant hedges, bushes, anything with thorns, small trees (e.g. Japanese maples), place potted plants, etc. near the corners.  Anything to prevent people from getting in the vicinity of the corners to begin with.
2. Cut the corners.  This probably won't be the easiest thing in the world, but it is definitely doable if you have the tools.  You'll need a circular saw that can do bevel cuts or a reciprocating saw.  (Circular saw would probably be the preferred method of cutting.)  I would highly recommend removing any screws/nails in close vicinity to where the blade will pass during cutting, as they can damage the blade or even cause kickback (which can cause a big owwie if the saw hits you.)  If the outer facade was load-bearing or otherwise increased the rigidity of the structure, then you will need to replicate that sturdiness somehow.  Post pictures for further advice.
3. Bevel/chamfer the edges with a router or circular saw capable of bevel cuts.  Fasten a temporary jig (guide) to control the path of the saw/router for best results.  Polish it up with a bit of sanding.  Stain/paint as needed.  Depending on the amount of material removed, original method of fastening (toenail, facenail, metal bracket, etc.), the importance of the facade in providing structural strength, you may have to install a bracket on the under, interior side of the deck to replace the strength supplied by the original material.
4. (The worst option.)  Install some form of padding.  It would be hard to avoid this creating a hideous appearance.

Comment: I think the planting idea has some merit because it will also help hide the nasty space under the deck.  I have to find something that will grow most upward instead of out into the yard though.